# flex direction column reverse for top and bottom children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to make this layout using `flex-direction: column-reverse` where button 1 and button 2 order is swapped without changing the html:

```
<button>2</button>
<button>1</button>
```

but I can't apply flex because it became 1 liner.

```css
.flex {
   display: flex;
}

button {
   width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
   width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="flex">
      <button>2</button>
      <button>1</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-direction:column; and then order:1 to button 1 ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif display flex make 2 row became 1 row which is not what I wanted

Comment: Your code doesn't have `flex-direction: column-reverse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `flex-direction` for the flexbox to align its elements vertically. By default, it arranges them horizontally. With `column-reverse`, the elements are arranged vertically in reverse order

```css
.flex {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

button {
   width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
   width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="flex">
      <button>2</button>
      <button>1</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A default setting in a flex container is `flex-direction: row`, which means that items will line up in a row.

If you want the items to stack vertically (in a column) then add `flex-direction: column` or `column-reverse` to the container.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse; /* new */
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="flex">
    <button>2</button>
    <button>1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```